# typecasting long to float using gcc libraries

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I am running a simple programme on Cnetos 6.2.0 version 64 bit machine.

```
int main()
{

int b = 1078085270;//1078085218;
float a;
a = (float)(b);

printf("val of a  is %f\n",a);

return 0;
}
```

The output of a is 1078085248. I changed the value to 1078085218.  still got the same result. I am not able to understand why or how the output gets corrupted or changed ?

Can anyone explain please ?

Comment: `float` doesn't have that much precision.

Comment: Please read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on how your machine handles floating point numbers and then think about your question.

Comment: My machine has 4 bytes for float data type storage. Could you please let me know how can I get to know about the exact precision of float?

Comment: @Learner Above 2^24, not all integers can be represented in the single-precision IEEE 754 floating-point format. Your number is way larger than this limit and the nearest representable `float`s are separated by something like 128.

Comment: `gcc` is a compiler, not a library. But apart from the `printf` call, the conversion is handled by the compiler, not by the library (though the compiler *might* generate a call to a library routine to do the conversion if there's no CPU instruction that can do it). Incidentally, the cast is unnecessary; `a = b;` does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the number `1078085270` in binary:

```
b1000000010000100100011010010110
```

An IEEE-754 single-precision float has only 24 bits of precision, but this number has more than 24 significant bits, so when you cast this number to `float`, it must be rounded.  The two closest numbers representable in `float` are:

```
b100000001000010010001101 0000000
b100000001000010010001110 0000000
```

(the spaces indicate the break between the 24th and 25th digits, the point at which the number is rounded).  Because your number is closer to the first number, it is rounded to that value, which is `1078085248` in decimal.